# Trying to convert a Spreadsheet into a webpage with variables and formulas, then submit to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, spreadsheet, xls

I've been working at this for the longest time, tried using PHPExcel but could only figure out how to do the reverse of what I want to do.

I need to take a spreadsheet with formulas and turn it into a web page, with a way to type in your own variables for the formulas. It's basic stuff, just multiplication and addition, but I simply can not figure it out. Help?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be able to do this with random spreadsheets, you'll probably need a decent component.  If it is just the one spreadsheet, it will probably be easiest to make your own.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addThem() {
        x = parseFloat($('#x').val());
        y = parseFloat($('#y').val());
        $('#total').val(x + y);
    }
</script>
<table class="outertable">
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="x"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>y</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="y"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>=</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total"></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:addThem()" value="Add"/>
```